# iText 7.1, C# - How to set table width to span the entire page?

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using iText 7(.1) with C#. I have a table with data. I want the table to take up the full width. How do I do that?

The [example code in the jumpstart tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/sharp/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks), that is:

```
var table = new Table(new float[]{4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1});
table.SetWidthPercent(100);
```

doesn't quite work for some reason -- Visual Studio will complain that `Table` doesn't contain a definition for `SetWidthPercent()`.

Comment: Table creation has been changed quite a lot in the run of the iText 7 revisions. Apparently the jumpstart tutorial could not keep pace...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
table.SetWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
```

The `setWidthPercent()` method is the method, you'd use in iText 7.0, but this changed in 7.1.

Comment: What is it in 7.1?

Comment: V7.2.5 still the same.